# Как локализовать jsp на русский язык?

Tags: jsp, jstl, resourcebundle

Пытаюсь локализовать приложение. Создал проперти файлы на английском и русском языках: i18n_en_GB.properties, i18n_ru_RU.properties. Вся информация подгружается. Кодировка страницы jsp UTF-8. Проперти файл на русском записан вот в такой форме:

```
login.label.signin = \u0410\u0432\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044C.
```

Но на jsp после мягкого знака и быквы "я" постоянно появляются пустые квадраты. Как от этого избавиться?